# Combine multiple records into one based on ID

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, fields-attributes

I have a table that has the building width for each side and I want to combine them together in GIS. I have attached an example in which I have 4 rows for one building, and I want only one row per building as shown on the picture. Is there a method in GIS?

[image]

Comment: Please update your tags with the software you are using.

Comment: Is this data just a table, or is it an attribute table of a feature class or shapefile? You're looking for a pivot table type function, and there are some other questions here about flattening tables. However most aren't set up like yours, which happens to be the simplest of cases since you already have a column for each value you want. In this case, you *can* summarize them just as suggested. The 'max' summary of 'north' for building 1 is '10', and so on for east, west, and south. Note that if this is just a table with no geometry, a Dissolve won't work (because there's nothing to dissolve).

Answer (score 1):

From the table you posted, it looks like your data is in a spreadsheet. If it is, create a pivot table or crosstab to summarize it.

In ArcGIS you could use Summarize on the building number field, and then get the Max value from the other fields.

Comment: Rather than Summarize I would suggest using Summary Statistics with Building Number as a CASE field and the other attributes as statistics fields. Notes about null values in the comments on the other answer still apply.

Answer (score 1):

Choose Geoprocessing->Dissolve.
Check "Building number" as the Dissolve Field.
Add "North" "East" "West" "South" as Statistic Fields, and choose "MAX" as the statistic type for each. This will work if your entries are all positive.

Comment: I believe that if any of your N,S,E,W fields has a <Null> value, the MAX method will fail. You can google "How to replace Null values," but it would be better to follow jlcrawf0's advice and do this operation in Excel.